# Blocking http/https requests (from 3rd party libs mainly) to non-whitelisted domains in an iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, react-native

I am developing a react native app, and for security reasons want to block **all** http traffic to all domains except my.domain on **IOS** **(cleartext or encrypted)**.

my info.plist:

```html
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>my.domain</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

but the result is that only unencrypted traffic (http) is blocked on all domains except my.domain, however i want to block all traffic on any domain other than my.domain.

What's the best strategy to achieve this result in iOS?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and review [ask].

Comment: Please un - close... I fixed the question

Comment: As you've seen, the `NSExceptionDomains` key simply tells iOS to allow **non-SSL** `http:` connections for the listed domains, but does nothing to prevent `https:` connections anywhere. You probably need to look at [Network Extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension).

Comment: Instead of trying to get this question re-opened, I'd suggest posting a new question with a bit clearer explanation of what you're trying to do. It would probably be very helpful if you also gave an example of a particular 3rd-party-lib you're using, and what http/https requests it's making that you need to block. It might be much more straight-forward to handle those *specific* cases, than to try and implement a Network Extension.